# Linux kernel debug symbols missing for some kernel builds

Tags: kernel, debug

I am trying to install debug symbols for the kernel to get SystemTap working.
I am getting the below error when I try to install debug symbols:

```
$ sudo apt-get install linux-image-$(uname -r)-dbgsym
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-image-5.4.0-153-generic-dbgsym
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-image-5.4.0-153-generic-dbgsym'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-image-5.4.0-153-generic-dbgsym'
```

I tried the unsigned version as below, it gave the same error.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-unsigned-$(uname -r)-dbgsym
```

As you can see I have the kernel 5.4.0-153 and am running Ubuntu 20.04.

After some searching, I found that debug symbols come from http://ddebs.ubuntu.com/pool/main/l/linux/
I can't find the debug symbols for build 5.4.0-153 in the above link as well.
Systemtap only recognizes the kernel debug symbols installed for the current version of the kernel used.

In this case, how can I install kernel debug symbols?